# C++: A small thing about loading a DLL and calling a function

Tags: c++, c, windows, hardware

I was looking for some dll or class to grab Hardware information of the client, and finally found it: 
http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/index.html

Can anyone tell me how to do the same as below, to call the function?
I used this code in C, and it works. Now I fail to convert it to C++.

```
  char* (__stdcall *GetIDESerialNumber)(BYTE);
  HINSTANCE DllInst = NULL;
  if (DllInst == NULL) DllInst = LoadLibrary("hardwareid.dll");
  if (DllInst)
  {
        GetIDESerialNumber = (char* (__stdcall*)(BYTE))GetProcAddress(DllInst, "GetIDESerialNumber");
        printf(GetIDESerialNumber(0)); 
  }
```

I'll be glad if anyone can do that for me, made some research and still failed to find an answer.

Comment: Why do you need to cenvert this to C++? Why this code is not sufficient?

Comment: This seems as valid C++ code, what error do you get ?

Answer (score 4):

<sup>your code is probably Windows specific and should be tagged as such. Posix systems would have `dlopen`.</sup>

C++ function names are often [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and you probably need to pass the mangled name to `GetProcAddress` (or to `dlsym` on Unix or Linux).

The name-mangling conventions are compiler- and system- specific.

Comment: Since he's trying to use the same function from the same DLL in both cases, I don't see how name mangling could be relevant.